# Install latest version of R with all the packages on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: r, installation

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I want to install R (version 3.5) on it. As the system version is older, it can't find this version from terminal line. I checked it with this command on the terminal line.

```
sudo apt-get install r-base=3.5
```

Which resulted in -

```
Version '3.5' for 'r-base' was not found
```

I want to install this version with all it's packages. What is the correct process? Can I get all the package files and installation files to install all of it in one go from my terminal? Please suggest me an appropriate way of achieving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install the newest version of `R` from a different PPA:

### 1. Add the PPA:

Currently, there are two different ones. For `R 3.5` and above:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)-cran35/"
```

And one for `R 3.4` (obviously the newer version is recommended):

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)/"
```

### 2. Next, you need to add `R` to your keyring.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
```

### 3. Update apt and install R (or r-base-dev if you wish to compile packages from source):

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install r-base
```

### 4. (optional) install RStudio via gdebi:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi-core
wget https://download1.rstudio.org/desktop/xenial/amd64/rstudio-1.2.5019-amd64.deb
sudo gdebi -n rstudio-1.2.5019-amd64.deb
rm rstudio-1.2.5019-amd64.deb
```

Steps are from [this PDF](https://github.com/leifeld/dna/releases/download/v2.0-beta.24/dna-manual.pdf).

Comment: Will this install all the packages?

Comment: No. And it is generally not advised to do that. There are currently more than 15,000 packages available on CRAN and nobody needs all of them. You can install some recommended packages from the PPA with `sudo apt install r-recommended` ([see](https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu/README)) but I would just install the things you need via `install.packages()`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: I just checked my R version. It is showing 3.2.3. It did not result in the latest version.

Comment: Strange, this should work on Ubuntu 16.04. Try removing the other PPA with `sudo add-apt-repository --remove "deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)/"` and add the one with cran35 at the end: `sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)-cran35/"`. I'm trying to investigate why there is a difference between the two at the moment.

Comment: Ok, the original command now adds the PPA for `R 3.4`. For newer version you have to use the one with `-cran35/` at the end.

Comment: Can anyone provide insight into why there are separate archives for R 3.4 and R >=3.5 ? Is 3.4 more stable; are there compatibility issues...? I just don't see why the default archive (`ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs)`) doesn't have the latest version.

Comment: I haven't found out why they made a new one either. I remember there were some compatibility issues but pretty much all packages should have been updated by now. I wonder what happens once R 4.0 is officially released.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to the PPA, you can add the official Ubuntu archive of The Comprehensive R Archive Network [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/) to your `sources.list` by doing:

```
sudo echo "deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

NB: The use of `cloud.r` allow the user to be automatically redirected to a nearby CRAN mirror.

Then, you will have to secure APT by providing the key for Ubuntu archives on CRAN by doing:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
```

Then update the list of repository, make upgrades if any and install `r-base`

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install r-base r-base-dev
```

This will install `r-base` and `r-base-dev`, that will provided as their names indicated it, the `base` for R. If you want additionnal packages, start `R` (in terminal, by typing R) and then install packages of interest by doing:

```r
install.packages("ggplot2") # an example of package
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think this is basically the same as my answer. `https://cran.rstudio.com` is just a CRAN mirror (one of several) and you write into `sources.list` directly instead of letting `apt` do that, but there is no real difference.

Comment: Essentially, you're right. I'm only following the official instruction of CRAN website. The `cloud.r` is preferred in order to the user to be redirected automatically to the nearby R mirror. I agree that it won't make a big difference. It was just to noticed it. BTW, I was not able to find `rstudio` mirror in the list of [CRAN mirror](https://cran.r-project.org/mirmon_report.html)